# How to find commit hash(s) / developer(s), date etc for a "given line" change in a file

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, devops, dvcs

This may be an odd question, but I thought I should check here.

I have a source code file in Git/Hg(Mercurial) distributed version control system.

Let's say at *line# 100*, I see:

```
if [[ `echo "${var}" | grep "system"` ]]; then env="env_system"; else env="env_local"; fi
```

Is this possible to find in Git(or similar DVCS) - How can I find, what commit(s) / commit hash(s) / developer(s) were involved for a "given line" in a file.

How can find which Git hash(es), developer(s) with date - were involved with adding/changing the above line in the file during the life of this file?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but if you are using an IDE like IntelliJ, using the Git plugin you may right click the margin of the line of code and annotate to reveal the author and date of the commit.

Comment: Why is this tagged mercurial?

Comment: @DaveInCaz I was curious as Hg (Mercurial) is another DVCS. It seems like it has `hg annotate -u -n` (ex: `hg annotate -u path/to/file | cat -n | sed -n 100,100p`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer to the first part of the question** (author of the last change of this line)

Sounds like a job for [`git blame`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame#Documentation/git-blame.txt--Lltstartgtltendgt) :

```
git blame -L 100,100 path/to/file
```

will also output the line itself after the information you wanted, but it might be good enough for whatever you intend to do?

And for a quicker use, maybe make an alias :

```
git config --global alias.bl '!f() { git blame -L $1,$1 $2; }; f'
```

then

```
git bl 100 path/to/file
```

Comment: that helped thanks. `--line-porcelain` option was also helpful.